# Typed variable declaration : Void initializer error in beanshell sampler Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

Hi I am trying to pass a a value from one regex extractor of one HTTP request to a beanshell sampler like below.

```
 var linkArr= ${PlanLinksArray_1}
```

Now I am using this linkArr variable in the subsequent request in the path like below

```
/hix/admin/planmgmt/viewqhpdetail/${linkArr}
```

While trying to do so I am getting the below error. The step fails at beanshell sampler with below error.

Can someone kindly advise ??

```
2015/06/12 16:32:10 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/06/12 16:32:11 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``var linkArr= hrGBCoZUbjLEV7zGwJpxEw ;'' : Typed variable declaration : Void initializer. 
2015/06/12 16:32:11 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``var linkArr= hrGBCoZUbjLEV7zGwJpxEw ;'' : Typed variable declaration : Void initializer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, why do you need Beanshell instead of calling `${PlanLinksArray_1}` directly in the subsequent request?

In regards to your question itself, Beanshell is more Java rather than JavaScript hence correct code will be something like:

```
String linkArr = vars.get("PlanLinksArray_1");
vars.put("linkArr", linkArr);
```

Where `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.